# Why does sort -n sort like this>

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have a file with the following lines:

```
4/3
4/7
3/5
3/6
2/4
```

When sorting using sort without any arguments, it arranges the lines like you would expect. When using sort -n the output is as follows:

```
3/5
3/6
4/3
4/7
2/4
```

I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Which version of sort are you using?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that on Linux with GNU Coreutils. What is your version of sort(1)?

Comment: GNU coreutils 8.25

Comment: cannot reproduce with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, coreutils 8.21

Comment: Do you have a weird locale configured? Try something like `env -i LC_ALL=C sort -n ...`.

Comment: Add output of `locale` to **your question**.

Comment: @Cyrus: In what locale is `2` numerically greater than `4`?

Comment: @KeithThompson: perhaps [Klingon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_language) ;) Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

A way to reproduce it is by adding zero width spaces in front of each line except for `2/4`:

```
U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE [Cf]
```

The following is a hex string containing said arrangement:

```
% echo "e2808b342f330ae2808b342f370ae2808b332f350ae2808b332f360a322f340a" \
  | xxd -r -p | sort -n
3/5
3/6
4/3
4/7
2/4
```

I doubt this is the case but maybe there is other non printable characters, you could try with a hex dump:

```
xxd -p < my_file
```

Comment: Or `cat -A my_file` for more legible output.